# Cannot resolve TargetProperty (UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle) on specified object

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, animation

Has anyone had this problem before?
I want to show an animation in windows phone 7, my sdk version is 7.1，I wanna rotate a picture as animation in my app.but it didn't work.

```
<Image.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="myTransform"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
        From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:5" 
        RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
    </Storyboard>
</Image.Resources>
```

Answer (score 5):

WP7 animations are not the same as WPF - one CompositeTransform object instead of a few for different purposes. First off, I would declare this animation in `PhoneApplicationPage.Resources`.

You need specify target animation and the property.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
<Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
    <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="myTransformPanel" <!-- Here is a object that
                                           you'd like to move e.g. StackPanel -->
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)"
        From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:5" 
        RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
    </Storyboard>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Also you need to set `CompositeTransform` for the object that you want to transform.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="myTransformPanel" >
         <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform></CompositeTransform>
        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
</Stackanel>
```